# Converting an already-uploaded file and saving it to a model's FileField

Tags: python, converting, django

Please review this:

```
from os import path, remove

try:
    video = Video.objects.get(id=original_video_id)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    return False

convert_command = ['ffmpeg', '-i', input_file, '-acodec', 
       'libmp3lame', '-y', '-ac', '2', '-ar', 
       '44100', '-aq', '5', '-qscale', '10', 
       '%s.flv' % output_file]                     

convert_system_call = subprocess.Popen(
    convert_command,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)

logger.debug(convert_system_call.stdout.read())

try:

    f = open('%s.flv' % output_file, 'r')
    filecontent = ContentFile(f.read())
    video.converted_video.save('%s.flv' % output_file, 
                     filecontent, 
                     save=True)
    f.close()

    remove('%s.flv' % output_file)

    video.save()

    return True
except:
    return False
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clean, easy to understand code. However:

Never hide errors with a bare except. Change

```
try:
    ...
except:
    return False
```

into

```
try:
    ...
except (IOError, AnyOther, ExceptionThat, YouExpect):
    logging.exception("File conversion failed")
```

Also, unless you need to support Python 2.4 or earlier, you want to use the files context manager support:

```
with open('%s.flv' % output_file, 'r') as f:
    filecontent = ContentFile(f.read())
    video.converted_video.save('%s.flv' % output_file, 
                               filecontent, 
                               save=True)
remove('%s.flv' % output_file)
```

That way the file will be closed immediately after exiting the `with`-block, even if there is an error. For Python 2.5 you would have to `from __future__ import with_statement` as well.

You might also want to look at using a temporary file from `tempfile` for the output file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the review! I have updated the snippet to be http://pastebin.com/9fAepHaL But I am confused as to how to use tempfile. The file is already created by the "convert_system_call" before I use it's name in the try/catch block. Hmm,, maybe I use tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()?

Comment: @Chantz: Yeah, exactly. If not you may end up with loads of temporary files in a current directory, where users  won't find them and they ever get deleted.

Comment: Lennart following your & sepp2k's suggestion I modified my code to be like http://pastebin.com/6NpsbQhz Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the points that Lennart made, there's just one minor thing I'd like to add:

You repeat the expression `'%s.flv' % output_file` four times in your code. You might want to store this in a variable like `filename = '%s.flv' % output_file`. This way there's less repetition and if you ever want to change the target file format, all you'll have to change are the `filename` and `convert_command` variables.

Comment: Makes sense. Will make the change. Thanks!

Comment: sepp2k following your & Lennart's suggestion I modified my code to be like http://pastebin.com/6NpsbQhz Thanks.